# Global Sections of a particular projective scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A=k[\![x]\!]$ and consider the closed subscheme $X=V_{+}(xy_2) \subseteq \mathbb{P}_A^1$ (where I write $(y_1:y_2)$ for the homogeneous coordinates in $\mathbb{P}^1$). I am confused about how the global sections of the structure sheaf on $X$ look like. Are they just $k$?

Comment: No, it is in fact isomorphic to $A$.

Comment: How do you prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X=V(x)\cup V(y_2)$, so write $V(x)=S, V(y_2)=T$ and note that $S=\mathbb{P}^1_k, T=\operatorname{Spec} A$. They intersect at one point, where $x=y_2=0$. One has an exact sequence $\mathcal{O}_S(-1)\to\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{O}_T\to 0$. Since $H^i(\mathcal{O}_S(-1))=0$, for $i=0,1$, we see that $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X)=H^0(\mathcal{O}_T)=A$.